# C++ std::destroy(T * pointer)

Tags: c++, stl

The STL code I am reading may be old...but the question is more related to C++ template grammar.

The question surrounds this stl template function:

```
template<class T> std::destroy(T *p) {
    p->~T();
}
```

I can't seem to find a  specialization of the std::destroy(T *) function. So it seems to me that the template function will instantiate same for "int" types, and invoke "int"'s destructor.  To make my point, I created this sample code that emulate the std::destroy. I call it my_destroy ih the example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

template <class T> 
void my_destroy(T * pointer) {
    pointer->~T(); 
}
int main()
{
    int *a;
    //a->~int();        // !!! This won't compile.
    my_destroy<int>(a); // !!! This compiles and runs.
}
```

}

To my surprise, this line doesn't compile:

```
a->~int();
```

But this line compiles:

```
my_destroy<int>(a);
```

My confusion is, I thought that `my_destroy<int>(a)` will be instantiated as the equivalent of `a->~int();`

To a question in larger context, when a STL container of `<int>` erases an element, how does the `std::destroy()` work?

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted, it's a legitimate question. +1

Comment: It's called a pseudo-destructor and has own, special rules. Essentially you can only use a *type-name* which is either a class/enum name or a typedef name.

Comment: It's the fact that you can't use a keyword to mean call to destructor. `typedef int INT; a->~INT();` compiles.

Comment: It is called `std::destroy_at`.

Answer (score 33):

Note that, while `a->~int();` doesn't compile, this does:

```
typedef int INT;
int* a;
a->~INT();
```

From the standard:

5.2.4p1 The use of a `pseudo-destructor-name` after a dot . or arrow -> operator represents the destructor for the non-class type denoted by `type-name` or `decltype-specifier`. The result shall only be used as the operand for the function call operator (), and the result of such a call has type void. The only effect is the evaluation of the postfix-expression before the dot or arrow.

From 5.2p1:

```
pseudo-destructor-name:
  nested-name-specifier_opt type-name :: ~ type-name
  nested-name-specifier template simple-template-id :: ~ type-name
  nested-name-specifier_opt~ type-name
  ~ decltype-specifier
```

And finally, 7.1.6.2p1:

```
type-name:
  class-name
  enum-name
  typedef-name
  simple-template-id
```

So, curiously, `int` is not syntactically a `type-name` (it's a `simple-type-specifier`) and so you can't call `~int()`, but `INT` is and so you can.

Answer (score 4):

For class types (non-scalar types), the expression

```
pointer->~T();
```

is essentially a function call (a *postfix-expression*). To identify the function to be called, the part `pointer->~T` is must be analysed. The `~T` is an *id-expression* IFF `T` is a *class-name*, identifying the destructor function.

Of course, `int` is not a class name. But if `T` is a *type-name* naming a scalar type, the same expression is parsed differently. The whole part `pointer->~T` is identified as a special *postfix-expression* called a *pseudo-destructor name*. With the following `()` the expression is considered a call of a *pseudo-destructor* (the rules in [expr.pseudo] forbid to do anything else with a pseudo-destructor name but to call it).

`int` itself is not a *type-name* [dcl.type.simple], but a *simple-type-specifier*:

> type-name:
>
> - class-name
> - enum-name
> - typedef-name
> - simple-template-id

That's why you can use a `typedef`'d `int` or `T` as in your example (*), but not `int` directly. The reasoning has been well explained by [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe).

The rules for pseudo-destructor calls are specified in [expr.pseudo]: "The only effect is the evaluation of the *postfix-expression* before the dot or arrow."

(*) from [temp.param]/3: "A *type-parameter* whose identifier does not follow an ellipsis defines its *identifier* to be a *typedef-name* [...]"

Comment: +1 for excellent backgrounder. I just named it as I see it. Perhaps I'm a bit too pragmatic to recall the standardese, but this is certainly informative

Answer (score 3):

The language allows these things to enable generic programming. However, your 'straight' invocation is not in generic code, hence it fails.

Another such case is

```
template <typename T> void foo()
{
    T instance = T(); // default constructor
}

foo<int>(); // will work
```

So, yes:

```
template <typename T> void foo()
{
    T* instance = new T(); // default constructor
    delete instance;      
}
```

will also work for builtin primitive types, because `T` is a typename in the scope ot the template.

Comment: @MooingDuck hmmm. That's because there's a difference between `int instance;` and `int instance = int();` - the latter value-initializes it, whereas the former leaves it uninitialized.